Do they use some Bayesian-frequentist amalgamate in astrophysics?
Below is a figure (highlighting is mine) from Madhusudhan et al. (2023). It caught my attention in a recent video by Becky Smethurst, where she explains some more context (but that's not necessary for my question).

What caught my attention was the simultaneous use of (Bayesian) posterior probabilities for model quantities and the (frequentist) language of "significance" and "non-significance" of those results.
Is astrophysics using some amalgamate of Bayesian and frequentist statistics? If so, how does it work? Is there a textbook treatment available that someone could point me to?

It might be better to pose this question to the area people are doing it in; they don't always use the terms quite in the way we would. It might not be that there's any inconsistency at all; it might at worst suggest a slight looseness of expression.

Looks like something to do with Bayesian Model Comparison and detection significance which is supposed to be an alternative to classical Null Hypothesis Testing. It seems to utilise posterior odds in the comparison. There are references throughout in the paper.

@Derf I did look up some of the references; in particular Benneke & Seager (2013) is very insightful, specifically their table 2 translating between "Frequentist Significance Values" and Bayes factors. Still feels like an unusual Bayes-frequentist hybrid, though, that I'd definitely like to learn more about.

This relates a bit to How to explain null hypothesis testing using Bayesian terms?.
Statistic significance is often equated with p-values and 'probability of the data', but we could more generally or abstractly state that: statistical significance is a clear distinction in the support of the data for absence versus presence of an effect.
Frequentist methods consider an observed effect significant if the null hypothesis is outside a $100-\alpha\%$ confidence interval. Or, if the data is unlikely given the null hypothesis.
The Bayesian method here considers an observed effect significant if the null hypothesis is outside a $100-\alpha\%$ credible interval. Or, if the null hypothesis is (relatively) unlikely given the data.
I wouldn't neccesarily consider it as an amulgate between frequentist and bayesian statistics. The consideration of 'significance' made here is purely a Bayesian credible interval.
